# In 3 phase induction motor how many phase will be generated in wound type and squirrel cage rotor?

Tags: induction-motor, electric-machine

In 3 phase induction motor how many phase will be generated in wound type and squirrel cage rotor? If we consider a generator when the rotor rotates there will be voltage induced in every pole of stator but for motor case our assistant said it is 1 phase.

Comment: Hello and welcome. You put the answer in your question (your assistant's answer). if you want to know why, you should rephrase your question.

Comment: @Sclrx Ok thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On a **Wound Rotor** Induction Motor,  the rotor windings are separate phases so the output is indeed 3 phase. If you look at the circuit below for a "slip recovery system" for a Wound Rotor Induction Motor, you will see that.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The rotor in a squirrel-cage induction motor has generated in it the same number of poles as the stator. However, the three phases in the stator are summed together to create a rotating magnetic field. So each set of three phase-windings produces one pair of poles in the stator and one pair of poles in the rotor. The rotor field rotates with respect to the rotor and rotates synchronously with the stator pole-pairs. Although the rotor field is rotating, we can not really say that he rotor currents have identifiable phases. The equivalent circuit of a three-phase motor does consist of three circuits each consisting of a stator circuit and a rotor circuit. However each phase circuit has only one magnetizing branch.